# Django admin login not working for superuser

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, anaconda, django-admin

I'm a newcomer to Django, so sorry if this question is bad. I have looked on the internet but have not been able to find a solution. I am trying to login to a superuser account I created with manage.py. I have not modified any file in my Django project, and am using Django 3.2.5. Every time I try to log in on the admin page it gives me this error: `Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive` (in the web browser of course). I know I am using the username and password that I used when creating the superuser account. I have created two super users the second to while trying to figure out what is going on with this error. I am using the default sqlite3 db. I am also using a anaconda virtual environment. I have also made sure to run migrations and I have flushed the database and tried again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by restarting my anaconda virtual environment. I do not know how it fixed it, but it worked.